# TouchableHighlight in a ListView different onPress behaviour based on Platform

Tags: react-native

I need to assign a different behaviour to a TouchableHighlight onPress.
I tried to wrap my code in a function, but I do not why when I call the function in this way:

```
onPress={(data) => this.myFunction(data)}
```

I have an error like `_this4.myFunction` is not defined.

I know that the problem is the `this` in my `renderRow()`, but I don't know how to solve it. I tried to bind the function in my `constructor` and also write `self = this`in my function, but no luck.

So I thought to use a ternary operator with something like this:

```
Platform.os === 'ios' ? onPress={} : onPress={}
```

but also this attempt failed.

Any help? I am a rookie in RN.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `constructor()`, I have added

```
this._renderRow = this._renderRow.bind(this)
```

and I could use this in the `TouchableHighlight onPress`

Answer (score 3):

I think you should do platform check inside the function that you are calling in onPress. Then you should write platform specific behavior for your touchable highlight.

```
            onPress:{()=>this.doIt()}
```

and inside doIt() you should do platform check then perform your platform specific code.

```
         doIt()
        {  if(Platform.OS === 'ios')
            {//do this on ios}

           if(Platform.OS === 'android')
             {//do this on android}
        }
```

For binding 'this' to function you may either use following for calling function doIt()

Use fat arrow binding in es6

```
     ()=>this.doIt()
```

that I have used above,
Or use this statement in constructor

```
     this._renderRow = this._renderRow.bind(this)
```

Comment: Hey. Thank you for the answer. The only problem of this method, that I have already tried, is that I got an error on the use of this. I think because it is in a Listview

Comment: @LoveToCode, why `this._renderRow = this._renderRow.bind(this) ` in constructor did the trick?

Comment: Through binding this you are passing the scope of 'this' to function _renderRow(), there are many ways to do that. You can refer to the link https://www.sitepoint.com/bind-javascripts-this-keyword-react/ @fifth